# react-native-google-places-autocomplete is not returning any results when searching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-platform

I have a react native component that is a google search for a location. I am using used the google places api with the hope that when a user starts typing a city or address, it will autocomplete and show a list of results. I intregrated the `react-native-google-places-autcomplete` npm package and create a api key in the google cloud console. I set everything up correctly, but no results are showing up.

component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { TextInput, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete'

import {Feather} from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import { SearchFilterContext } from '../../Context/SearchFilterContext'
import { PropertiesContext } from '../../Context/PropertiesContext'

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
const aspectWidth = deviceWidth - 16

const SearchComponent = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [autocompelete, setAutoComplete] = useState([])

  const {currentSearch, setCurrentSearch, results} = useContext(PropertiesContext)
  const {setResults, getProperties, setLoading} = useContext(PropertiesContext)

  const SubmitSearch = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setCurrentSearch(search)
    setResults([])
    resetSearch()
  }

  const updateSearch = (value) => {
    setCurrentSearch(value)
  }

  const handlePlaceSelect = (data, details) => {
    console.log(data, details);
  };

  const resetSearch = () => {
    getProperties()
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.SearchBar}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Search"
          styles={{
            textInputContainer: {
              marginBottom: 8,
            },
            textInput: {
              height: 32,
              color: 'black',
              fontSize: 16,
              backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
            },
            predefinedPlacesDescription: {
              color: 'black',
            },
          }}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            console.log(data, details)}}
          fetchDetails={true}
          query={{
            key: '...',
            language: 'en',
          }}
        />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  SearchBar: {
    width: aspectWidth,
    height: 36,
    paddingBottom: 8
  },
})

export default SearchComponent
```

This is where I setup the api key:

[image: API enabled]

[image: API key activated]

Here is what is showing up when i start typing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-google-places-autocomplete` does not work with restricted API Keys. Notice how you have the key restricted to iOS apps.

This is because `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` doesn't use native code.

You can add the `onFail` prop to see any issues going on.

`onFail={(err) => console.log(err)}`